# Importing multiple CSV files into Google Sheets using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

So I am doing a personal project for my home administration. I would like to automatically when opening my spread sheet (adminSheet.gs) to import .csv files. It is possible to do this manually, but I would like to automate this as I have to import 30+ .csv files, and more coming. I have enabled google apps script (GAS). However GAS is new for me, I am a bit comfortable with Javascript, however it has been a while since I was in college.. I hope you can help me out!

Here are the facts.

I have multiple .csv files, all with a different name. They are located in the same folder called CSVfolder. This folder is within the main folder MAINfolder in Google Drive. They are seperated by the delimiter ; (semicolon). The CSV files have the same data structure and the first row of each .csv file is the same. This first row has been put already in the sheet adminSheet.gs, serving as the header row called HEADER. So the first row needs to be deleted of each .csv file when imported.

I will upload new .csv files in the CSVfolder. These file name follow the following naming structure. ID_01-09-2020_30-09-2020.csv or ID_01-10-2020_31-10-2020.csv. ID followed by a changing date. (the .csv data will be for that period of time. overlapping or duplicated data will not occur, as I will choose the dataset manually). However this would make it of course very neat.

When I open the adminSheet.gs (located in the MAINfolder), it needs to automatically recognise any new .csv file and merge that into the existing adminSheet.gs with all the other (previously imported) .csv data. The new .csv file should merged below the fixed header row HEADER and above the previously imported .csv file. (this can also be explained as: between the HEADER and the data already in the adminSheet.gs) (this can also be explained as: the new data from the .csv should come above the old data already in the adminSheet.gs).

What Google Apps Script could do this?

Comment: Your question is too broad, it should focus on a specific issue. What research did you do till now? What did you try? Is there any code you're working on? Also, when you talk about the `CSVfolder`, is this a Drive folder, or is it in your local computer?

Comment: I have tried many copy paste solutions found throughout the internet, but could not find one single solution that does this job. I am not working on any code right now, as I am not comfortable enough to write code. 
CSVfolder is in the drive.

Comment: What you are requesting is possible to accomplish in google apps script.  However, opening files can take a long time so there is the script timeout issue to deal with.  Personally, I would keep a list of the filenames that have already be imported and run the script once for each import to start out with until I kind of have any idea of how long it takes then I might migrate to a less hands on approach.  I read csv gps files from dropbox every day and calculate my exercise time from them and import the data into my personal assistant script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how the following code works:

- gets data from the csv file as an array
- inserts a number of rows after the header row
- sets the array in the sheet
- moves the csv files to an archive folder after importing them so they are not imported again
- then moves to the next file until there are no more files to import

You will need to create an archive folder for the csv files to be stored in after they have been imported. I generally make one inside the folder containing the csv folders for this purpose.

In the code, you will need to provide the folder IDs for the archive folder and the root folder (folder that contains your CSV folder) and the name of the destination sheet in your spreadsheet. These can all be set in the first four variable in the code. (I already set `csvFolderName` to 'CSVfolder' per the information you provided above.

After saving this code, create a trigger on it to run on open.

Here is the code:

```
function importCSVFiles()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  const csvFolderName = 'CSVfolder';                                       // Folder containing csv files and the Archive folder
  const rootFolderId = 'id_of_folder_containing_CSVfolder';                // Root folder
  const archiveFolderId = 'id_of_archiveFolder';                           // Archive Folder
  const destinationSheetName = 'name_of_destination_sheet_in_spreadsheet'; // destination sheet in spreadsheet
  
  const root = DriveApp.getFolderById(rootFolderId);
  const archiveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(archiveFolderId);
  
  const fileName =/ *.csv/;
  
  var rootFolders = root.getFolders();
  
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  var csvArray = [];
  
  while (rootFolders.hasNext()) 
  {
    var folder = rootFolders.next ();
    Logger.log('folder.getName()',folder.getName());
    if (folder.getName() === csvFolderName) 
    {
      importCSV(folder);
    }
    else 
    {
      var csvFolder = folder.getFoldersByName(csvFolderName);
      while (csvFolder.hasNext()) 
      {
        importCSV(csvFolder.next());
      }
    }
  }
  
  function importCSV(folder) 
  {
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) 
    {
      var file = files.next();
      Logger.log('file.getName()',file.getName());
      csvArray = file.getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-8");
      csvArray = Utilities.parseCsv(csvArray);
      csvArray.shift();
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(1,csvArray.length);
      sheet.getRange (2,1,csvArray.length,csvArray[0].length).setValues(csvArray);
      
      file.moveTo(archiveFolder);
    }
  }
}
```

If it seems like you are having issues with the delimiter, you may need to set it specifically as a custom delimiter by substituting the above line of code `csvArray = Utilities.parseCsv(csvArray);` for `csvArray = Utilities.parseCsv(csvArray,';');`

Comment: I only had to add:
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
above: 
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);

Comment: sorry about that. i added it to the code above.

Comment: Is it possible any of this scripts functionality has been dis-continued since date of posting, as it doesn't work for me. The log simply displays "Info folder.getName()" and then completes execution, Ive checked all my variables 100 times and they are fine, and the root folder has multiple csv's and the archive folder in... Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this is exactly the functionality I have been trying to achieve!!

Comment: I had some problems here and there and this is my edited working version https://gist.github.com/blessanm86/396b4c40cc44f03c16c43fab04bdda8a